# JSONObject is null even though I get data from facebook graph api

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api, android-asynctask

I'm working on Facebook app and getting data from facebook graph api. In AlbumsActivity I'm executing AsyncTask where in loandInBackground I call getJSONString method which should execute Facebook api's GraphRequest and return jsonObject from its response. 
[image]
[image]

As onCompleted method in GraphRequest is void, I've created JSONObject with null value and initializing it inside onComplete. But when I return json, it's giving null. I think problem is that json is being returned before GraphRequest.executeAsync is done.

Comment: You are working on FaceBook App. What is the new change in it ?
Altough please post some more code this is barely under standable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the value of `json` in another thread and when the function reaches the `return statement` the value of `json` has not been set by the `callback`. This is the reason you are getting the json value as `null`.

Comment: @Yusuf Why are you using `AsynkTask` when you have already been given a callback for  GraphRequest. Try doing your `mParserManager.getAlbum()` inside the `onComplete()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JSONArray data= response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");

or

jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("graphObject");

This is the relevent data I think you are wishing for.